# treehouse iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am making my first app.

I'm doing the treehouse tutorials and I've made a button and a label from a single view template.  When I press "play" or "run" the simulator just brings up either a white screen (for ipad) or nothing (for iphone).  What am I missing?  I've searched on google, but it's such a generic question that I couldn't find what I was looking for without explaining myself.  What obvious little thing am I missing here?

Comment: Could you specify what the "treehouse" tutorials are?

Comment: Yes, they are great tutorials found here: http://teamtreehouse.com/library/ios-development/build-an-iphone-crystal-ball-app/getting-started/what-is-an-iboutlet

As you can see it is very basic.  This is the code I'm trying to run:
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.quoteLabel.text = @"Be thee smart";

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try setting your initial view controller in your MainStoryboard.

Comment: by "setting you initial view controller" do you mean the 
"@interface ViewController : UIViewController" line that is in my .h file?  Or how do I do this?  Sorry to be so ignorant guys, I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: yes, I am.  Is there another way that is better?

Answer (score 0):

I think Sam is trying to say that in your project settings, you have a choice of "Main Interface" (which must be a XIB file) or "Main Storyboard". If you set this your app will know which view to show on startup.

Comment: I go under File->Project Settings and it only gives me the ability to change from Default, Project, or Custom.  I don't see Main Storyboard or Main Interface anywhere.  But thank you for trying to help

Comment: File > new > file > user interface > storyboard. Build your interface within this file. Also in your project navigator click the very top option which is your App name, then under targets select your App name again (It's to the left). Finally specify what the name of your Main Storyboard is under iPhone / iPod Development Info Once you have built your interface like you did your XIB file, you can see in my answer I posted an image with a red box around is initial view controller check box.

Comment: Ok, so I did that.  The Storyboard it created has a lot of presets in it and I tried doing "cntl Drag" into the .h file but every time I try my xcode crashes and I can't get past that :/

Comment: ok, nevermind.  I just ran it and it ran my code that was already written in my original MainStoryboard. So it's working!  Thank you guys :)